# interpreting results from auto.arima R

Tags: r

First time using doing any forecasting and was looking into using auto.arima but I'm not really sure what the results mean, basically from 'Coefficients' onwards.
Can someone please be kind enough to give me an explanation

```
Series: total[, "total"] 
ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2        mean
      1.1055  -0.4207  138805.107
s.e.  0.2020   0.2002    4664.756

sigma^2 = 53468931:  log likelihood = -205.36
AIC=418.72   AICc=421.39   BIC=422.7
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the main model fitted by `autoarima()` converges to:

Y_t = 138805.107 - 0.4207·Y_(t-1) + 1.1055·Y_(t-2)

For the rest of the output, the standard deviation (s.e.) for each of the coefficients is also shown (necessary to see if the coefficients are significant). Finally, sigma^2 is the variance of the residual values, the log-likelihood is a "quality measure" of the model (the closer to zero the better) and necessary for comparing this fit against others) and the AIC, AICc and BIC are other "quality measures" based of the log-likelihood, sample size and amount of coefficients estimated.